# Elasticsearch - analyzer plugin missing?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to programmatically create an index in Elasticsearch using the following code snippet:

```
String indexName = "index";
String indexJson = createIndexJson();

elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(indexName, indexJson);
```

Where `createIndexJson()` returns the following string:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "video": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "properties": {
            "en": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "english"
            }
          }
        },
        "desc": {
          "properties": {
            "en": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "english"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And `elasticsearchTemplate` is created as:

```
new ElasticsearchTemplate(
    new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300)));
```

If I run this code I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [index.mappings.video.properties.desc.properties.en.analyzer] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:346)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:310)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.settings.AbstractScopedSettings.validate(AbstractScopedSettings.java:284)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService.onlyCreateIndex(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:229)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService.createIndex(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:209)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.create.TransportCreateIndexAction.masterOperation(TransportCreateIndexAction.java:81)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.admin.indices.create.TransportCreateIndexAction.masterOperation(TransportCreateIndexAction.java:39)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.masterOperation(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:88)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction$2.doRun(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:167)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsExecutors$1.execute(EsExecutors.java:135)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction.doStart(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:164)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction$AsyncSingleAction.start(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:127)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.doExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:105)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.master.TransportMasterNodeAction.doExecute(TransportMasterNodeAction.java:55)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:167)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:139)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(HandledTransportAction.java:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(HandledTransportAction.java:69)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:66)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport$RequestHandler.doRun(TcpTransport.java:1555)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.EsExecutors$1.execute(EsExecutors.java:135)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.handleRequest(TcpTransport.java:1512)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1382)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:297)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:413)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:265)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:241)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1359)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:935)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:645)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:545)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:499)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:459)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [index.mappings.video.properties.desc.properties.en.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
        ... 51 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [index.mappings.video.properties.title.properties.en.analyzer] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
        ... 51 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown setting [index.mappings.video.properties.title.properties.en.type] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings
        ... 51 common frames omitted
```

So basically it complains about this part of the index definition:

```
"en": {
  "type": "text",
  "analyzer": "english"
}
```

If I use the same index definition and use it to create an index using Elasticsearch REST API `PUT localhost:9200/index` everything works fine with both Elasticsearch 5.6.6 and Elasticsearch 6.2.1

I've noticed that with this code request does not go to Elasticsearch server, so apparently they fail validation on the client side.

What can be the cause of this validation failure? Do I need to add a plugin to my Elasticsearch Client configuration?

Comment: Check the createIndex response to see if your index was actually created

Comment: @sramalingam24 The index is not created. The exception is thrown by createIndex() and the execution is interrupted

Comment: Hmm, what is the version of server and client? Do they match?